# When God said to Eve that her desire would be for her husband, was this a curse?

Tags: genesis, hebrew

Genesis 3

> <sup>**16**</sup> To the woman He said: “I will sharply increase your pain in childbirth; in pain you will bring forth children. Your desire will be for your husband, and he will rule over you.”

Is this a curse?

Comment: Highly related: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13234/what-kind-of-desire-was-given-to-eve

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was deceptively posed, answered and accepted by a single user under the guise of two separate accounts, and was not a genuine question. Merging into the near-duplicate.